# Package with correct jdk

Tags: java, maven, jar

After spending an entire day trying to understand why maven does not want to switch jdk based on the entry in the compiler-plugin (see  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html) I discovered that the compiler is switching correctly, but the jar tool is not.  Consider the following facts:

1. I've added the multi-catch block in my code as a test. If I set the  tag to java 7, it compiles.  If I change to 1.6 it breaks.  This is expected behaviour.
2. However, if I remove the diamond operator (i.e. compiling in both), and I compile with Java 6, I get the following in my manifest file:

   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
   Created-By: Apache Maven
   Built-By: jaco
   Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_147-icedtea
   ...

This is of course rather ambiguous. Is there any way to set the correct "jar tool" as well so that the manifest file will reflect the version being used?

Comment: That part I got...duh! Let me rephrase: "How can I get the manifest file to reflect the version of the java compiler used."

Comment: Even if you tell the java compiler to use 1.6 you still use your 1.7 JDK underneath.  In that sense the entry is accurate.   Considered compiling with a Java 6 JDK if it is so important?

Comment: Without being rude, you're wrong.  If you use the compiler-plugin you can specify the actual executable java compiler.  There is compatibility issues if you compile to 1.6 on 1.7 and then run on 1.6. ...and no, we cannot change that right now as this will involve getting signing a lot of forms and flying to Nigeria for a week :-)

Comment: yes, for the _compiler_ (if you fork to my understanding).  For _jar_ all this doesn't happen and "jar" is invoked by the JDK "underneath" (i.e. the one Maven runs in), and that is what he wants too.

Comment: Correct, thank you. I think I should just live with it for now.  Thanks for the remarks.

Comment: I think we had a misunderstanding.  "Forking" does not effect "jar" only "javac".  Sorry & Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One way here, using Maven/Ant:

[Maven: Adding Custom Attributes and Build Timestamp to Manifest](http://twit88.com/blog/2008/02/20/maven-adding-custom-attributes-and-build-timestamp-to-manifest/)

Answer (score 0):

Toolchains plugin may help here, not sure, haven't tried it.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-toolchains-plugin/